# Checkbox within ColdFusion code

Tags: html, checkbox, coldfusion

I'm trying to display data from database and add a checkbox at the end of each row. I've tried html tags and CF tags but for the last few hours I'm getting errors.. Any help would be great as I'm totally new to ColdFusion. Heres the code :

```
<cfset a = "BGCOLOR =###IIF(myQuery.currentrow MOD 2, DE('E6E6E6'),DE('C0C0C0'))#" />

<cfscript>
    For (i=1;i LTE myQuery.recordCount; i=i+1)


     writeoutput ("<TR " & a & "><TD>" & i & "</TD>" &
      "<TD>" & myQuery.UserID[i] & "</TD>" &
      "<TD>" & myQuery.FName[i] & "</TD>" &
      "<TD>" & myQuery.SName[i] & "</TD>"&
      "<TD>" & myQuery.Phone[i] & "</TD>"&
      "<TD>" & myQuery.DateJoined[i] & " </TD>"&
      "<TD>" & myQuery.Address[i] & "</TD>"&
      "<TD>" & <cfinput type="Checkbox" name="post_home">  & " </TD></TR>");


    </cfscript>
```

Last  line (line 55) causing error..
Thanks in advance

Invalid CFML construct found on line 55 at column 37.

ColdFusion was looking at the following text:
checkbox

```
  The CFML compiler was processing:

  An expression beginning with writeoutput, on line 48, column 1.This message is usually   caused by a problem in the expressions structure.
  A script statement beginning with writeoutput on line 48, column 1.
  A script statement beginning with For on line 45, column 9.
  A cfscript tag beginning on line 44, column 2.
  A cfscript tag beginning on line 44, column 2.
  A cfscript tag beginning on line 44, column 2.

  The error occurred in C:/inetpub/wwwroot/sem2/aShowUsers.cfm: line 55
  53 :           "<TD>" & myQuery.DateJoined[i] & " </TD>"&
  54 :           "<TD>" & myQuery.Address[i] & "</TD>"&
  55 :        "<TD><input type="checkbox" name="post_home"></TD></TR>");
  56 : 
  57 : 
  Resources:
  Check the ColdFusion documentation to verify that you are using the correct syntax.
  Search the Knowledge Base to find a solution to your problem.
  Browser   Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko)      Chrome/26.0.1410.64 Safari/537.31
  Remote Address    ::1
  Referrer      http://localhost/Sem2/adminmainpage.cfm
  Date/Time     13-May-13 10:08 PM
  Stack Trace


 coldfusion.compiler.ParseException: Invalid CFML construct found on line 55 at column 37.
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.generateParseException(cfml40.java:13130)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.jj_consume_token(cfml40.java:13001)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.FunctionParameters(cfml40.java:6523)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ComplexReference(cfml40.java:6381)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.VariableReference(cfml40.java:6300)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.PrimaryExpression(cfml40.java:6105)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.UnaryExpression(cfml40.java:5955)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ExponentialExpression(cfml40.java:5912)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.MultiplyDivisionExpression(cfml40.java:5865)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.IntegerDivisionExpression(cfml40.java:5846)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ModExpression(cfml40.java:5827)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.AdditionExpression(cfml40.java:5780)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ConcatExpression(cfml40.java:5761)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ComparisonExpression(cfml40.java:5614)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.NotExpression(cfml40.java:5564)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.AndExpression(cfml40.java:5536)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.OrExpression(cfml40.java:5517)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.XorExpression(cfml40.java:5498)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.EqvExpression(cfml40.java:5479)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ImpExpression(cfml40.java:5460)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.HookExpression(cfml40.java:5415)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.expr(cfml40.java:5399)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfScriptExpression(cfml40.java:2576)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.SimpleStatement(cfml40.java:643)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfscriptStatement(cfml40.java:1595)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.ComplexStatement(cfml40.java:1710)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfscriptStatement(cfml40.java:1530)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfscript(cfml40.java:1455)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfml(cfml40.java:4568)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfelse(cfml40.java:442)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfif(cfml40.java:316)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfml(cfml40.java:4554)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfelse(cfml40.java:442)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfif(cfml40.java:316)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.cfml(cfml40.java:4554)
at coldfusion.compiler.cfml40.start(cfml40.java:4994)
at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parsePage(NeoTranslator.java:694)
at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parsePage(NeoTranslator.java:675)
at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.parseAndTransform(NeoTranslator.java:428)
at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:370)
at coldfusion.compiler.NeoTranslator.translateJava(NeoTranslator.java:147)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache$1.fetch(TemplateClassLoader.java:436)
at coldfusion.util.LruCache.get(LruCache.java:180)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader$TemplateCache.fetchSerial(TemplateClassLoader.java:362)
at coldfusion.util.AbstractCache.fetch(AbstractCache.java:58)
at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get_statsOff(SoftCache.java:133)
at coldfusion.util.SoftCache.get(SoftCache.java:81)
at coldfusion.runtime.TemplateClassLoader.findClass(TemplateClassLoader.java:609)
at coldfusion.filter.PathFilter.invoke(PathFilter.java:101)
at coldfusion.filter.LicenseFilter.invoke(LicenseFilter.java:30)
at coldfusion.filter.ExceptionFilter.invoke(ExceptionFilter.java:94)
at coldfusion.filter.ClientScopePersistenceFilter.invoke(ClientScopePersistenceFilter.java:28)
at coldfusion.filter.BrowserFilter.invoke(BrowserFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.NoCacheFilter.invoke(NoCacheFilter.java:46)
at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:38)
at coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
at coldfusion.filter.CachingFilter.invoke(CachingFilter.java:62)
at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:204)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)
at coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:928)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:414)
at org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpProcessor.process(AjpProcessor.java:203)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:539)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:298)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: You need to post the full error message. (Without it, we are just guessing).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're missing quotes around your `<cfinput>` tag. You need to use a single quote here to concatenate properly.

```
<cfscript>
for ( i=1; i <= myQuery.recordCount; i++ ) {

  writeoutput ("<tr " & a & "><td>" & i & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.UserID[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.FName[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.SName[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.Phone[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.DateJoined[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & myQuery.Address[i] & "</td>" &
  "<td>" & '<input type="checkbox" name="post_home">' & "</td></tr>");

}
</cfscript>
```

Alternatively you could put your last line all in single quotes.

```
'<td><input type="checkbox" name="post_home"></td></tr>');
```

Comment: Nothing against Matt's answer. But unless there is a specific reason for using `cfscript`, you might consider switching to `cfoutput` instead. In this case a simple `cfoutput` is a little more readable and straight-forward IMO.

Comment: @Leigh I'm with you Leigh, tags make this much easier to read. I only used script because that's how the question was asked.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it the easy way, without using cfscript.

```
<cfoutput query = "myQuery">
<tr>
    <td>#myQuery.userid#</td>
    ... other display fields
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="post_home" value="#something#"></td>
</tr>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: Since poster's are often struggling with syntax problems already, you might want to test your code samples for syntax errors before posting them ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that you don't have `a` defined in your example and the check boxes will not have a value to pass as it's not defined. Also, don't put hashes around the `i` var.

```
<cfscript>
        for ( i=1; i <= myQuery.recordCount; i++ ) {

             writeoutput ("<tr " & myQuery.currentRow MOD 2 ? '##E6E6E6' : '##C0C0C0' & "><td>" & i & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.UserID[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.FName[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.SName[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.Phone[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.DateJoined[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td>" & myQuery.Address[i] & "</td>" &
                "<td><input type='checkbox' name='post_home'></td></tr>");

            }
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Can you update your code please... I'm not seeing anything obvious. Also FYI - when you set a in line one, it will never change. Replace `a` in your code with `& myQuery.currentRow MOD 2 ? '##E6E6E6' : '##C0C0C0' &`. Even better would be to use class names.

Comment: it's because in your last line it won't concatenate the line properly with `"` as the enclosure and used in the string.

Comment: Ah, thanks @MattBusche ! I should have caught that. Dims replace the input double quotes with single quotes or escape them.

Comment: it's one of the fun gotchas that happens at least once a week to me